# Doubts of purity and impurity

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-basis, islamic-scholar

Asalamu alaykum.
I have this problem with doubts that I would like to clarify.
Whenever I wash myself either after urinating or passing stool. The water from private part drips on either my foot or my clothes, so I don't know whether I should just ignore it or not. I am obsessed with these kinds of things.
Plus, if I have a suspicion that there is impurity covering the entire house, whether it is on clothes, sofas, any object and even on my family members, how do I tackle this, because most of them go out, either on work, or school so I have suspicion that the impurity is spreading, so I don't know as to how to tackle this situation. I try to make dua with certainty that Allah will do something for me, but then doubts start to fog my mind. Sometimes, I feel like my prayer is not accepted because of this impurity. And I don't know if I suffer from OCD, or urinary incontinence, I just have these doubts an obsessions to over clean, which causes a problem, e.g. my hands get itchy when applying hand sanitizer or really dry when outside in cold weather, and I'm suspicious whether it's because o fmy habit to really scrub my hands when cleaning them and cleaning more than usual.

Brother or sister please help me. Jazakallah Hu khairan.

Answer (score 0):

Consult a scholar or an imam. From the looks of it you seem to be suffering from waswas (devils whispers). Increase your dhikr and adhkar and read more Quran to combat this. I do recommend speaking with your parents first as they may be able to help you. May Allah ease your condition